# TXT Import Add Field Using Partial Filename

Tags: vba, ms-access, txt

I am trying to import multiple .txt files from a directory into an Access table using VBA.

I have code that currently works that imports the data and moves the files to an archive directory.

What I need to do is add the first part of the filename as field in the table, namely the date.

The file format is MMDDYYYY_LbxReport.txt (ex 02082022_LbxReport.txt)

Here is the code that I have working, and I commented out what I tried to add to fix my problem:

```
Private Sub Command9_Click()

On Error GoTo bImportFiles_Click_Err
    
    Dim objFS As Object, objFolder As Object
    Dim objFiles As Object, objF1 As Object
    'Dim dteEntry As Variant             'added this variant for use in UPDATE cmd
    Dim strFolderPath As String
    
    Set objFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFolder = objFS.GetFolder("\\*****************\upload\SSDTestLBXa\")
    Set objFiles = objFolder.files
    
    For Each objF1 In objFiles
        If Right(objF1.Name, 11) = "xReport.txt" Then  'LBX level report capture
                'dteEntry = Left(objF1.Name, 8)
                'dteEntry = Left(dteEntry, 2) & "/" & Mid(dteEntry, 3, 2) & "/" & Right(dteEntry, 4)  'added to reformat into standard date format
            DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, "lbxlevelspecs", "lbxlevel", strFolderPath & objF1.Name, False
            'CurrentDb.Execute "Update lbxlevel" & "Set EntryDate=" & dteEntry & "", [] 'getting syntax errors here
            Name strFolderPath & objF1.Name As "\\**************\upload\SSDTestLBXa\Archive\" & objF1.Name 'Move the files to the archive folder
             
        End If
        


    Next
    
    Set objF1 = Nothing
    Set objFiles = Nothing
    Set objFolder = Nothing
    Set objFS = Nothing
    
'Call Site_level

MsgBox ctr & "All volumes imported", , "Volume Import"
    
bImportFiles_Click_Exit:
    Exit Sub
    
bImportFiles_Click_Err:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " " & Err.Description
    Resume bImportFiles_Click_Exit
    
    
End Sub
```

I saw a similar thread for this question, but I can't get the syntax right, and the OP's code was very different from what I have that's working so far.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: "add the first part of the filename as field" - that sounds like you want to create a new field which doesn't really make sense. What happens when you try code - error message, wrong result, nothing?

Comment: When you import the text file the target MsAccess table will not have a column for your Date. You can run `currentdb.execute("'ALTER TABLE tablename ADD EntryDate DATETIME")`. You can then run your UPDATE command

Comment: and... for `'CurrentDb.Execute "Update lbxlevel" & "Set EntryDate=" & dteEntry & "",` add  a space between 'lbxlevel' and 'Set'; also add quotation marks around the date and remove the square brackets (what do they represent?)

Comment: Thanks for your response! I tried the Update command exactly as you have it and I'm still getting "Syntax error in UPDATE statement" error message. It also doesn't seem to like the command to Alter/Add the field, I tried what you suggested above, replacing with my table name, and I get "Access database engine cannot find input table or query 'ALTER TABLE lbxlevel ADD EntryDate DATETIME'. Make sure it exists and that its name is spelled correctly"

Answer (score 0):

This is how you would construct the update statement:

```
Public Sub doit()

   Dim dteEntry As Variant
   dteEntry = Left("02142024_SomeName.txt", 8)
   dteEntry = Left(dteEntry, 2) & "/" & Mid(dteEntry, 3, 2) & "/" & Right(dteEntry, 4)  'added to reformat into standard date format
   CurrentDb.Execute "ALTER TABLE lbxlevel ADD EntryDate DATETIME"
   CurrentDb.Execute "Update lbxlevel " & "Set EntryDate='" & dteEntry & "'"
End Sub
```

Because it needs apace before 'SET', and quotation marks around the date.

EDIT: I added the ALTER TABLE, this tests successfully on my side.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I tried the Update command exactly as you have it and I'm still getting "Syntax error in UPDATE statement" error message. It also doesn't seem to like the command to Alter/Add the field, I tried what you suggested above, replacing with my table name, and I get "Access database engine cannot find input table or query 'ALTER TABLE lbxlevel ADD EntryDate DATETIME'. Make sure it exists and that its name is spelled correctly"

Comment: I edited the answer, adding the alter table there. The error message for the ALTER TABLE you reported indicates that the lbxlevel table does not exist; is this the wrong tablename? was it created as a result of your dosmd.transfertext command?

Comment: Nope, the lbxlevel table existed before running this code. I also tried adding the EntryDate field to the table and skipping the Alter command, but I'm still getting UPDATE syntax error

Comment: Just before the `command.execute "UPDATE...`  statement, add `DEBUG.PRINT "Update lbxlevel " & "Set EntryDate='" & dteEntry & "'"` and share what is printed on the Immediate window here.

Comment: After adding the suggested DEBUG line of code, I still get an error, "Syntax error in UPDATE statement"

Comment: yes, the debug.print was to show us the full SQL statement by printing it in the immediate window. Can you see the immediate window; use CTRL-G, if not? After your run attempt (which results in the 'Syntax error in UPDATE statement') the Immediate Window will show the SQL statement sent to MsAccess. Copy that for us here (I suspect that there is a problem with the date string (it is not meant to solve the problem, just to diagnose it).